# Difference between JBPM and BPEL/ESB

Tags: esb, bpel, jbpm, jbi

what is difference between JBPM and BPEL(and ESB)?
Would you please explain them?

RGDS

Comment: I think the question you meant to ask was what's the difference between BPMN (2.0) and BPEL. And while there are significant differences in the two approaches (BPMN seems to be slightly more abstract and BPEL more oriented around (web service) orchestration), the largest difference seems to be that BPMN is more popular in Europe and South America and BPEL is more popular in the US and Canada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not much familiar with JBPM. But it seems to be a Business work flow which can work with java services or basically java based process. Not only with web services.

BPEL is a standard to write work follows with web services. Always BPEL language used to integrate the web services and define processes based on that. Here is an sample I have written for that[1].

ESB is primarily used for mediation and transform messages. When you integrate different types of systems, the message flow between them may vary. So people can use ESB as a mediator. And also some ESBs provides service integration as well. WSO2 ESB[2] is such an ESB you can use.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/05/integrate-business-rules-bpel

[2] http://wso2.org/library/esb

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, ESB + BPEL is a technical solution for an integration problem. If you want to use jBPM5 just to do integrations thats fine and you probably will use jBPM5 with an ESB for all your mediation and transformation of your messages. The power of BPMN2, a standard notation to describe business processes will help you to describe more high level/business oriented scenarios than just simple system integrations. The concept of human interaction is heavily embedded in the language and in the jBPM5 infrastructure. Think about the fact that your models (business processes) can be shared and understood by business/non technical people and they will be able to validate, improve and change those definitions when the business reality changes.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

jBPM is BPMN based. This is a java based solution to your workflow problem.
BPEL is also solves the workflow problem, but the approach is entirely different. It is web service based.
BPEL from a syntax perspective is more complex than BPMN but is considered more extensive.

The right comparison should actually be between BPMN and BPEL I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Similarity

- >Both can be used for orchestration

difference in terms of technology.

> JBPM  has BPMN2.0 Notation  for Workflow designer and workflow XML  it generate is BPM2.0 compliance(which means you can import it in any BPMN2.0 tool) .It is assumed to be Product Analyst friendly whereas BPEL has its own specifications and its considered more developer oriented

BPM should only be used where there is a human task otherwise ESB fulfills everything from orchestration to transformation to Rules to CEP